# How do i change the background when a certain key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, background, keypress, keyboard-events

How do I change the html background in different colors when someone types 1-8 in a html input WITHOUT pressing enter?

for example pressing 1 makes the html background green, pressing 2 makes it red etc.

Comment: what have you tried? The site is for specific question/answers, not a service for writing your code.

Comment: Read over [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the *keydown* event to a function that will change the background-color style property depending on the pressed **keyCode**:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 49: // 1
        setBackgroundColor('red');
        break;
      case 50: // 2
        setBackgroundColor('green');
        break;
      case 51: // 3
        setBackgroundColor('blue');
        break;
      case 52: // 4
        setBackgroundColor('yellow');
        break;
      case 53: // 5
        setBackgroundColor('black');
        break;
      case 54: // 6
        setBackgroundColor('white');
        break;
      case 55: // 7
        setBackgroundColor('purple');
        break;
      case 56: // 8
        setBackgroundColor('#333');
  }
});

function setBackgroundColor(color) {
    document
      .querySelector('body')
      .style
      .backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Here's a working sample:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpMEyQ

Key code reference table:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Answer (score 0):

When you do `e.keyCode == someValue` and the like, you can change the image source then:

```
// Number
if (event.keyCode == 49) {
      $("#id").css("background-color", "green");
}
```

ASCII value of a number is from 48 to 57. You can write similar if conditions for all numbers